# Python scipy fsolve "mismatch between the input and output shape of the 'func' argument"

Tags: python, scipy

Before I go into my problem, I've searched the relevant threads on stackoverflow with the same problem:

- [input/output error in scipy.optimize.fsolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10505378/input-output-error-in-scipy-optimize-fsolve)
- [Python fsolve() complains about shape. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21734602/python-fsolve-complains-about-shape-why)
- [fsolve - mismatch between input and output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22413454/fsolve-mismatch-between-input-and-output)
- [I/O shape mismatch when using scipy.optimize.fsolve on 2-dimensional anonymous function array variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27073407/i-o-shape-mismatch-when-using-scipy-optimize-fsolve-on-2-dimensional-anonymous-f)

From what I understand reading about this error,

> raise TypeError(msg)
>   TypeError: fsolve: there is a mismatch between the input and output shape of the 'func' argument 'fsolve_function'

The issue is that the shape of the input and output are *not* the same.

In my code example below, I have the following:

- input, `initialGuess` (the starting estimate to be used in the `fsolve` function in scipy.optimize). The input, `initialGuess` has 3 starting estimates for coordinates x,y and z. Therefore I expect my starting input estimate to have always three inputs.
- output, `out` (non-linear simultaneous equations). In this example I have 4 non-linear equations.
- `scipy.optimize.fsolve` raises the error highlighted above, because the input and output do *not* have the same shape. In my particular case, I want my input to always have three values (to guess the initial starting points of x, y, and z). The output in this case has 4 non-linear equations to solve using the initial input estimate.
- Side note: Using the same input and output shape, eg. input shape of 3 [x, y, z] and output of 3 non-linear equations, `fsolve` will do the calculation accordingly. I'm just wondering how could you extend `fsolve` to use let's say equal or more than 4 non-linear simultaneous equations with just 3 input initial estimates?
- Code below:

  ```
  from scipy.optimize import fsolve

  def fsolve_function(arguments):
      x = arguments[0]
      y = arguments[1]
      z = arguments[2]

      out = [(35.85 - x)**2 + (93.23 - y)**2 + (-39.50 - z)**2 - 15**2]
      out.append((42.1 - x)**2 + (81.68 - y)**2 + (-14.64 - z)**2 - 27**2)
      out.append((-70.90 - x)**2 + (-55.94 - y)**2 + (-68.62 - z)**2 - 170**2)
      out.append((-118.69 - x)**2 + (-159.80 - y)**2 + (-39.29 - z)**2 - 277**2)

      return out

  initialGuess = [35, 93, -39]
  result = fsolve(fsolve_function, initialGuess)
  print result
  ```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`fsolve` is a wrapper of MINPACK's [`hybrd`](http://www.math.utah.edu/software/minpack/minpack/hybrd.html), which requires the function's argument and output have the same number of elements. You can try other algorithms from the more general [`scipy.optimize.root`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root.html) that do not have this restriction (e.g. `lm`):

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve, root

def fsolve_function(arguments):
    x = arguments[0]
    y = arguments[1]
    z = arguments[2]

    out = [(35.85 - x)**2 + (93.23 - y)**2 + (-39.50 - z)**2 - 15**2]
    out.append((42.1 - x)**2 + (81.68 - y)**2 + (-14.64 - z)**2 - 27**2)
    out.append((-70.90 - x)**2 + (-55.94 - y)**2 + (-68.62 - z)**2 - 170**2)
    out.append((-118.69 - x)**2 + (-159.80 - y)**2 + (-39.29 - z)**2 - 277**2)

    return out

initialGuess = [35, 93, -39]
result = root(fsolve_function, initialGuess, method='lm')
print(result.x)
```

Incidentally, it cannot find the actual zero --- is there supposed to be one at all?

You can also force `fsolve` to use your function if you supply it an initial guess with a "bogus" fourth variable:

```
initialGuess = [35, 93, -39, 0]
```

but I'm not sure how reliable are the results in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the response. 


I am expecting a solution that will have some error in the answer, but within an acceptable threshold.

Comment: By default `root` uses `method='hybr'`, and therefore throws the same error as `fsolve`. But it allows you to specify other methods that do not do that (as I illustrated). As for the error — are you sure there is a root? Maybe you need to look for a minimum instead (using an appropriate function)?

Comment: The line `result = root(fsolve_function, initialGuess, method='lm')` works. I needed to add a specific method, which was `lm`.

Thanks again, I think this solves my question.